# Чем отличаются абстрактные функции от виртуальных?

Tags: ооп, php

Чем отличаются абстрактные функции от виртуальных?

Comment: начем с того, что абстракная, но не виртуальная функция - это уже странно. Хотя в php может быть по разному.

Comment: В php все функции виртуальные

Answer (score 3):

Абстрактная функция указывает на то, что в данном классе *нет реализации* этой функции, но она должна быть реализована в классах-потомках.

Абстрактные функции бывают полезны, когда от класса-предка наследуются несколько классов-потомков с различными реализациями одного и того же действия. Тогда, используя переменную типа класса-предка с абстрактной функцией, можно вызывать эту функцию. В зависимости от того, на объект какого класса указывает переменная, будет вызвана нужная реализация функции.

Поэтому абстрактными могут быть только виртуальные функции.

Обычно создание объекта класса, имеющего абстрактные функции, приводит к выводу компилятором предупреждения. А вызов абстрактной функции во время выполнения обычно приводит к выводу ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

> В потомках переопределять можно любые функции, в чем фишка вируальной?

Разница именно в том, что виртуальный метод переопределяет реализацию базового класса, а не виртуальнай нет. Т.е. если бы php разделял методы на виртуальные и не виртуальные, то следующий код:

```
class A {
    function test() {
        $this->foo();
        $this->bar();
    }

    /* virtual */ function foo() {
        echo "A::foo()\n";
    }

    /* NOT virtual */ function bar() {
        echo "A::bar()\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function foo() {
        echo "B::foo()\n";
    }

    function bar() {
        echo "B::bar()\n";
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

Выдал бы:

```
B::foo()
A::bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактная функция является виртуальной, но у неё нет тела.
Это просто пустое место, зарезервированное для функции, которая должна быть определена в классе-потомке.

Comment: В потомках переопределять можно любые функции, в чем фишка вируальной?

Comment: нет, не все, смотря какой доступ стоит **(public,privat,protected)**

Comment: приватные функции даже по логике нельзя переопределить. Потому что наследник не может обращаться к приватным полям предка. Но некоторые, создав функцию с таким же именем, думают, что они ее переопределили. А они просто создали приватную функцию.

Answer (score 0):

абстрактный метод не имеет реализации и должен быть определен в дочерних классах;
виртуальный метод - может быть как абстрактным, так и иметь реализацию, разница, **для С++,** заключается в том, что **если метод не указан как виртуальный то, даже если он переопределен выше, то в базовом классе будет игнорироваться переопределение**. То есть, на примере ПХП, в примере ниже, метод getSelf() вызывает именно тот метод getName(), который определен в базовом классе, несмотря на то, что он вызывается из класса Child где и переопределен.

```
class Base {

   static function getName(){
       return 'base';
   }

   function getSelf() {
        echo self::getName(); // равносильно: echo Base::getName()
    }

   function getVirtual(){
        echo static::getName()
    }
}

class Child extends Base {

  static function getName(){
       return 'child';
   }
}

$Child = new Child()
$Child->getSelf(); // 'base'
$Child->getVirtual(); // 'child'
```

Если утрировать, то можно сказать, что в пхп методы поумолчанию виртуальные, то есть автоматически будет выполняться метод определенный на самом верху, а в С++ наоборот, надо указывать virtual, что бы методы базового класса использовали переопределенный метод, те:

```
class Base {
   protected function _name(){ return "base"}

   public function getName(){
       return $this->_name();
   }
}

class Child extends Base {
   protected function _name(){ return "child"}
}

$Child = new Child()
$Child->getName();// PHP вернет 'child', а C++: 'base'
```

Но если в классе Base функцию getName() объявить как virtual, то результат будет одинаковым.

При этом в С++ нет ключевого слова abstract и для объявления абстрактной функции просто создают функцию без тела и объявляя её как виртуальную, последнее нужно именно для того чтобы базовый класс искал её реализацию в дочерних классах, а не пытался выполнить **не имплементированную** функцию.

PS: про другие языки не знаю